# In react with hooks, how do I copy and array, and then reverse it?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, react-bootstrap

I have 2 arrays:

```
function App() {
  const [historyText, setHistoryText] = useState([]);
  const [reversedHistoryText, setReversedHistoryText] = useState([]);
```

The historyText is working fine, but I want to reverse it.  So I thought I would first copy the array to a temp array:
I tried this:

```
setReversedHistoryText([...reversedHistoryText, historyText]);
```

and

```
setReversedHistoryText(historyText);
```

But neither way actually copied the array to the new array.  What am I doing wrong?

** Update
I'm now able to add it to another array, but its missing the last entry each time.

```
    setHistoryText([...historyText, tempComp]);
    setReversedHistoryText(historyText.slice().reverse());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close but also forgot to reverse it.

Because state updates are asynchronous, you can't get the latest state right after you call the state updater.

If this is the only place where `historyText` and `setReversedHistoryText` gets updated, you can just append and prepend the new item into the arrays

```js
setHistoryText([...historyText, tempComp])
setReversedHistoryText([tempComp, ...reversedHistoryText])
```

If you need to update `setReversedHistoryText` only in this function you can  create the next `historyText` array and then use that value to update the reversed array

```js
const nextHistory = [...historyText, tempComp]
setHistoryText(nextHistory)

// then
setReversedHistoryText([...nextHistory].reverse())

// other variations
setReversedHistoryText(nextHistory.slice().reverse())

setReversedHistoryText(Array.from(nextHistory).reverse())
```

Comment: Could there be a timing issue involved, when I show the reversedText, its always missing the last entry I added to historyText?
    setHistoryText([...historyText, tempComp]);
    setReversedHistoryText(historyText.slice().reverse());

Comment: Posted in original question.

Comment: @baumli Yes, post how you update `historyText` and i will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy historyText array use:

```js
setReversedHistoryText(historyText.slice());
```

or

```js
setReversedHistoryText(...historyText);
```